# Fitting a rear derailleur

Tags: derailleur

I'm building a bike from old bikeparts, but i've got a problem. The part that connects the derailleur with the frame doesn't fit, and I thought I would find something on chainreactions, but I can't see anything. Any suggestion?

Comment: Pictures would probably help.

Comment: Pictures would definitely help. It's hard to guess what you mean by "the part that connects the derailleur with the frame." The hanger? The bolt that goes into the hanger?

Answer (score 3):

2 suggestions.

1. Only change the derailleur, since the new frame should have its own derailleur hanger.
2. derailleurhanger.com